# How to check opened/closed ports on my computer?

Tags: netstat

How to check the opened/closed ports on my computer?

I used `netstat -a` on command line.

- Does the port status "LISTENING" indicate that the port is open?
- Is any port, that is not shown in the output, closed?

Comment: Check [this post on AskUbuntu!](http://askubuntu.com/a/394383/335497).

Comment: @Justgivemeaname: `nmap` is a tool to check for open ports on *another* host. If you can run `netstat` on a machine, it's much faster and reliable to use it.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: Didn't know about `netstat`, so I learned that. It says in the link that it should be used from another host, though. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I see what ports are open on my machine?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9368/how-can-i-see-what-ports-are-open-on-my-machine)

Answer (score 184):

There's a few parameters to [`netstat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/netstat.8) that are useful for this :

- `-l` or `--listening` shows only the sockets currently listening for incoming connection.
- `-a` or `--all` shows all sockets currently in use.
- `-t` or `--tcp` shows the tcp sockets.
- `-u` or `--udp` shows the udp sockets.
- `-n` or `--numeric` shows the hosts and ports as numbers, instead of resolving in dns and looking in /etc/services.

You use a mix of these to get what you want. To know which port numbers are currently in use, use one of these:

```bsh
netstat -atn           # For tcp
netstat -aun           # For udp
netstat -atun          # For both
```

In the output all port mentioned are in use either listening for incoming connection or connected to a peer** all others are closed. TCP and UDP ports are 16 bits wide (they go from 1-65535)

** They can also be connecting/disconnecting from the peer.

Answer (score 83):

You can use this command:

```
netstat -tulnp | grep <port no>
```

If it shows some process its used. Its closed(not used) if there is no output.

Answer (score 24):

Another alternative command line easy to use to find out which process is using a port:

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:$PORT | grep LISTEN
```

I added the next function in my .bash_profile,

```
function pslisten {
    echo `lsof -n -i4TCP:$1 | grep LISTEN`
}
```

and now run "pslisten 5060" to see who is grabing my SIP port.

It's work with Apple Mac OS X too.

Answer (score 17):

> Is the port status "LISTENING" indicated that the port is opened?

Yes. It means that some service is listening to that port on your computer for incoming connection i.e. this port is open for establishing new connections.

> Any port that are not shown in the output indicated that it's closed?

Yes. Remember `netstat -a` will show all active (*listening*) and passive (*non-listening*) connections i.e. the ports that are acting as both server (some services are listening to these ports for connections from a different machine/process) and established (connections are established on these ports regardless of the fact the host/a service can be a server or client)

All TCP and UDP ports belong to a category called sockets and there are a whole lot of those. To view socket info you can check `man ss`.

Comment: Thanks. you wrote that `-a` means server and established. Does "server" means ports that are being listened at by some services? Does "established" mean ports where there are existing connections regardless of it is a client or server's port? Then what kinds of ports does `-a` not show?

Comment: I don't think the `-a` option means "all active" sockets; it just means "all". netstat shows all active sockets by default, but leaves out the passive sockets (open, listening). By using the `-a` option both active and passive sockets are shown.

Comment: @EgonOlieux Thanks. I stand corrected; edited the answer.

Comment: @heemayl The second part of your answer is still not correct. A TCP socket in the "listening" state can never be a connection; it is not connected to anything, it is only listening. Listening TCP sockets are also called passive sockets because of this. If a client attempts to connect to a (listening) socket on a server, a new socket will be created on the server to establish a connection with the client. A socket which is part of an established connection is called an active socket.

Answer (score 11):

Another option is [ss](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ss). It's much easier to use....

The below command will only output a list of current listening sockets.

```
root@server:~# ss -l

    Netid  State      Recv-Q Send-Q                                     Local Address:Port                                                      Peer Address:Port   


u_dgr  UNCONN     0      0                                                      * 23353                                                                * 23352                
u_dgr  UNCONN     0      0                                                      * 568                                                                  * 362                  
u_dgr  UNCONN     0      0                                                      * 14836                                                                * 14837                
u_dgr  UNCONN     0      0                                                      * 20446                                                                * 369                  
u_dgr  UNCONN     0      0                                                      * 22877                                                                * 369                  
u_dgr  UNCONN     0      0                                                      * 504                                                                  * 347                  
u_dgr  UNCONN     0      0                                                      * 16298                                                                * 369                  
u_dgr  UNCONN     0      0                                                      * 23343                                                                * 369                  
u_dgr  UNCONN     0      0                                                      * 24125                                                                * 369                  
u_dgr  UNCONN     0      0                                                      * 24617                                                                * 369                  
u_dgr  UNCONN     0      0                                                      * 23352                                                                * 23353                
u_dgr  UNCONN     0      0                                                      * 23334                                                                * 369                  
u_dgr  UNCONN     0      0                                                      * 17113                                                                * 369                  
u_dgr  UNCONN     0      0                                                      * 16957                                                                * 369                  
u_dgr  UNCONN     0      0                                                      * 14793                                                                * 362                  
u_dgr  UNCONN     0      0                                                      * 23345                                                                * 362                  
u_dgr  UNCONN     0      0                                                      * 24070                                                                * 369                  
udp    UNCONN     0      0                                                      *:sunrpc                                                               *:*                    
udp    UNCONN     0      0                                                      *:981                                                                  *:*                    
udp    UNCONN     0      0                                                     :::sunrpc                                                              :::*                    
udp    UNCONN     0      0                                                     :::981                                                                 :::*                    
tcp    LISTEN     0      128                                            127.0.0.1:85                                                                   *:*                    
tcp    LISTEN     0      128                                                    *:ssh                                                                  *:*                    
tcp    LISTEN     0      128                                                    *:3128                                                                 *:*                    
tcp    LISTEN     0      100                                            127.0.0.1:smtp                                                                 *:*                    
tcp    LISTEN     0      128                                                    *:8006                                                                 *:*                    
tcp    LISTEN     0      128                                                    *:sunrpc                                                               *:*                    
tcp    LISTEN     0      128                                                   :::ssh                                                                 :::*                    
tcp    LISTEN     0      100                                                  ::1:smtp                                                                :::*                    
tcp    LISTEN     0      128                                                   :::sunrpc                                                              :::*
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually there is a better way to see what ports you have open. The issue with `netstat` or `lsof` is that they query network stack and actually do not connect to the machine but instead trying to see what is running on the system. The better approach is to use `nmap` like so:

```
nmap -sT -O localhost
```

To see open ports.

Answer (score 4):

Or this might help by using watch, then play around with what you want to see.

```
sudo watch -d -n0 "netstat -atnp | grep ESTA"

sudo watch -d -n0 "netstat -tulnp | grep ESTA"
```

Comment: -a conflicts with -l, -a grabs all whether ESTABLISHED or LISTENING, and -l just grabs LISTENING, so in reality it is '-ltnp' tcp, '-lunp' udp or '-ltunp' tcp+udp

Answer (score 1):

1. Try this to get a list of opened ports in that range.

   ```sh
   for p in {1..1023}
   do
      (echo >/dev/tcp/localhost/$p) >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "$p open"
   done
   ```
2. And this command will show what is it!

   ```sh
   cat /etc/services | grep {PORTNumber}
   ```