# Connect to Ubuntu 18.04LTS server via xrdp

Tags: 18.04, remote-desktop, ubuntu-gnome, xrdp

**EDIT** *I was having user/pass issues. Now they are solved, and I found another problem.*

I mean to connect for the first time to an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server via xrdp from Win 10.
I can already connect with `vino-sever` and tigervnc client.
I connect via VPN.

I followed [this](https://www.hiroom2.com/2018/04/29/ubuntu-1804-xrdp-gnome-en/), but when connecting via xrdp I do not get the *Authentication Required dialog* mentioned in the link, step 3.
Instead, I get

[image: VNC problem]

**How can I fix this issue?**

**Do I have to kill `vino-server`, or can they both be active simultaneously?**

**Do I have to enable RDP port 3389? How?**
I guess this is ok, since when the xrdp window is open, I see

```
$ sudo netstat -antup | grep xrdp
[sudo] password for myuser: 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:3350                :::*                    LISTEN      15449/xrdp-sesman   
tcp6       0      0 :::3389                 :::*                    LISTEN      15460/xrdp          
tcp6       0      0 xx.xx.xx.xxx:3389       xx.xx.xx.xxx:61469      ESTABLISHED 15869/xrdp
```

and when I close it, I see

```
$ sudo netstat -antup | grep xrdp
[sudo] password for myuser: 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:3350                :::*                    LISTEN      15449/xrdp-sesman   
tcp6       0      0 :::3389                 :::*                    LISTEN      15460/xrdp
```

Comment: why don't you stop the others and try connection with xrdp alone and see what happens?

Comment: And of course if your connection via port 3389 then that port aught to be open on the server!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen - How do I check if port 3389 is open, and open it if not?

Comment: where is this server hosted? Nonetheless check your firewall rules, if you didn't create one then it's not done automatically but check

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen - Server hosted at a local company (I do not know if this answers the question).
Still I am not sure how to check if port 3389 is open.
As for the firewall, I guess this means it is no problem:
`$ sudo ufw status verbose`
</br>
`Status: inactive`

Comment: are the two machine at the same location?

Comment: Look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/538208/how-to-check-opened-closed-ports-on-my-computer for how to check which ports are opened

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen - 1. Machines not at the same place, now.
2. Please see updated OP (header).

Answer (score 1):

There is no enough information in your question to provide a 100 % working solution... Your issue is probably related to the fact that you are running an not up to date Ubuntu 18.04 version.  We are guessing that you are running **Ubuntu 18.04.2.**

As described in this [post](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13390), in Ubuntu 18.04.2, the xorgxrdp package does not get installed because of missing dependencies....

To fix your issue, you have multiple options

**Option 1**

use the easy to use x[rdp-installer-v1.1.sh](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=14093) script that will detect and fix the possible missing dependencies.  Please read the info provided in the post to learn how to use the script properly...

**Option 2**

Upgrade your Ubuntu 18.04.x with the latest updates (which will bring your Ubuntu to 18.04.4) and remove/install the xrdp package manually using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp 

sudo apt-get install xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04
```

Note : To check which version of Ubuntu you are running, from a terminal console, you can issue the following command

```
lsb_release -a
```

Hope this help

Till Next Time

See Ya